# How to bind input keyup value to a variable in component.ts?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following in my `component.ts` file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-loop-back',
  template: `
    <input #box (keyup)="0">
    <p>{{box.value}}</p>
  `
})
export class LoopbackComponent implements OnInit{ 
    sampleString: string;

    contructor(){}

    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Basically whatever I typed in the `<input #box (keyup)="0">` will be shown immediately in the `{{box.value}}`. As this is purely in the html file, I am wondering how can I bind the input `{{box.value}}` to `sampleString: string;` in my `component.ts` so that I can use it somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can bind the method on `change` event in input element and update the string value

> class file

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
    })
    export class AppComponent  {

       sampleString: string;

       updateBox(e) {
         this.sampleString = e.target.value; 
       }

    }
```

> Template File

```
<input #box (keyup)="0" (input)="updateBox($event)">
  <p>{{box.value}}</p>
<p>This is sampleString Value: {{sampleString}} </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular two way binding as shown below

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-loop-back',
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="sampleString">
    <p>{{sampleString}}</p>
  `
})
export class LoopbackComponent implements OnInit{ 
    sampleString: string;
   contructor(){}

    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this if you want to use only HTML an not 2 way binding,

```
<input #box (keyup)="sampleString = $event.target.value">
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vltr6p?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**